# Magento development environment on windows with debug capability

Tags: windows, debugging, magento

I have seen hundreds of post on how to setup an Magento development environment for Windows. But nowhere i could find a good tutorial on this works with proper debugging enabled. I have tried many IDE's and debugging frameworks (Zend, Xdebug) but i can't find a way to actually get this to work.

It would be great if i could set a break-point in an .phtml file so i can see what is going on and check all variables/objects.

Any (experienced) Magento developers who can explain on how to setup a proper development environment for Magento on a windows machine.

Hope to get some feedback....

Comment: At one point I had Netbeans working with a debugger (can't remember which one) but it was WAAAYY too flaky.  It would work a little, and only sometimes. Lost a lot of hours on it.  Might have been related to the version of zend debugger, xdebug, or wamp that I was using, dunno.  I couldn't get Eclipse to work properly either. Oh how I miss a descent debugger!  It took a while but now I am proficient enough with Magento to not *need* a debugger to get stuff done, but oh how it is painful!!!  Oh, and if you have some $$ you can try out Zend Studio, they claim it is integrated well.

Answer (score 2):

## Here is a simple step-by-step

1. Download the latest version of [Z:WAMP](http://sourceforge.net/projects/zwamp/files/)
2. Extract Z:WAMP wherever you like.
3. Download the [XDebug DLL](http://www.xdebug.org/files/php_xdebug-2.1.0-5.3-vc9.dll)
4. Copy the XDebug DLL to {zwamp directory}/vdrive/.sys/php/ext/
5. Add the following text to the bottom of the {zwamp directory}/vdrive/.sys/php/php.ini file

   ```
   [xdebug]
   zend_extension="/.sys/php/ext/php_xdebug-2.1.0RC1-5.3-vc9.dll"
   xdebug.remote_enabled=1
   xdebug.remote_connect_back=1
   ```
6. Run {zwamp directory}/zwamp.exe and accept the security messages for Apache and Mysql.
7. Delete everything under {zwamp directory}/vdrive/web/
8. Copy your magento project into the {zwamp directory}/vdrive/web/ directory
9. Download the latest version of [NetBeans PHP](http://netbeans.org/downloads/) and install it.
10. Start netbeans and click File > New Project
11. Click the *PHP* Category, Select the *PHP Application with Existing Sources* option
12. Click **Next**
13. Click **Browse** on the *Sources Folder* option
14. Select the {zwamp directory}/vdrive/web directory
15. For *PHP Version*, Select version *5.3*
16. Click **Next**
17. For *Project URL* enter "http://127.0.0.1/"  (Magento had/has a problem with names that do not have a TLD)
18. Click **Finish**
19. Wait for the *Scanning Projects..* to finish (bottom right status bar, it takes a while)
20. Open a code file, add a breakpoint, and run in debug mode (Ctrl-F5).
21. **Profit!**

### To turn off the 'break on start' option

1. Select *Tools* > *Options*
2. Select *PHP*
3. Select the *General* tab
4. Under Debugging, un-check the *Stop at first line* option
5. Click **Ok**

Comment: Just for anyone curious, **xdebug.remote_connect_back** was added in xdebug 2.1 and just initiates a debug session with the IP that originated the request.

Comment: Hi Lee,

I followed your guide but it still doesn't seem to work for some reason.
Netbeans is trying to get to connect to xdebug but can't for some reason, it prompts that i should add the following statements to php.ini:

xdebug.remote_enabled=on
xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp
xdebug.remote_host=127.0.0.1
xdebug.remote_port=9000

Hope you can help me further. Will this also work for the Magento .phtml file that contain php code, or will it cause problems because it is seen as a template file?

Frank

Comment: Not sure exactly what you did wrong but I verified this as I was writing by following my own steps. I would do this first, add an info.php file to the root of you magento install with a call to phpinfo() in it.  This will let you see all the settings for PHP.  Just search that page for 'xdebug' to verify the extension is loading at all.  Also, the message that netbeans is giving is for version before 2.1 that didn't support the remote_connect_back option. Those settings will still work, but it's easier to use the connect back instead of setting a static IP.

Comment: @Frank:
First of all create .php page with `phpinfo();`to check if the xdebug extension is loaded.


I suggest you to use xdebug with (Xdebug-helper 4 Chrome)[https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/eadndfjplgieldjbigjakmdgkmoaaaoc] or (easy xdebug 4 Firefox)[https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/easy-xdebug/]